# Taxonomy views listing url to follow site url structure

Tags: 7, views, path-aliases, taxonomy-terms

This is part of my site structure

A node gets part fo url alias from term and parent terms
mysite.com/term:name/term-child:name/node:title (Those are replaced with actual tokens)

Lenght of the alias may chanche depending on how many child terms there are
it may be food/banana/chiquita or cars/race/ferrari/red/enzo

What I would like to do, is to have pages like listing views that show nodes under that term (not parent term or child term).

so food will show nodes tagged with food (not nodes tagged with banana) and cars/race will show nodes tagged with race (not nodes tagged with cars or Ferrari).

I've tried taxonomy display but does not seems to work as expected.

I've set up term alias to follow same site structure so Ferrari term has got the alias cars/race/ferrari.

I'm using taxonomy menu and it works reeally well and it does the job but I cannot change view mode. I would like to change it to teaser or a custom view mode.

My questions are:
1) using taxonomy menu, how can i change taxonomy view mode?
2) is it possible to get same result with views?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you lookup https://drupal.org/project/path_alias_xt module ?

Comment: Nope, I need to change view mode of nodes under a core term page.